# check if array of type node is full c++

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

I'm practicing the question of making a hash table using only arrays.

I have a `Hash_Entry myMap[128][128]`.

Can I initiate all values to `NULL` or 0 even though it's type `hash_entry`?

and if I can't my issue is checking when the second-dimension array is full.

I thought of doing

```
is_Full(arr){
    if(arr.length()-1.key!=0 && arr.length()-1.value!=0){
           return false;
    }
    else return true;
 }
```

Is that I good implementation?

OR I thought of having a second array that increments a count for each bucket then testing if that count is equal to the bucket size

Comment: Either way should work (if by "bucket" you mean "row").

Comment: @Beta yes I do mean row.  However what if the last item coincidentally is (0,0) for key and value? Is there any way to set the actual index to just 0?

Comment: You *defined* a NULL `Hash_Entry` as one that had `key`=0 **or** `value`=0. If those are valid values for a non-NULL `Hash_Entry`, then you chose them badly. If there is no pair of values that a non-NULL `Hash_Entry` cannot have, then that approach won't work.

Comment: @Beta thank you for the follow-up.  It seems my second idea of implementation would be better. :)

Comment: Whatever weird language is that, it's not C++. If you want to tag your question "C++", it must, logically, show C++ code, and not something that looks like Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This code is certainly not C++. Assuming what you're trying to accomplish actually IS in c++, you can write a simple template to check if a member of `std::array` is equal to a member-provided `emptyValue`.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, size_t N, T emptyVal = NULL>
bool arrayIsFull(const std::array<T, N> &arr) {
    return !std::any_of(
        std::cbegin(arr),      // |   const iterators
        std::cend(arr),        // |__ c++11 and up
        [](const T &val) { return val == emptyVal; } // simple lambda to check if any member is equal to the expected empty value.
    );
};
```

Checking if they are all full is trivial.

```
static std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> twoDimArr;

void checkIfAllFull(void) {
    bool allFull = std::all_of(
        std::cbegin(twoDimArr),
        std::cend(twoDimArr),
        [](const auto &oneDimArr) {return arrayIsFull(oneDimArr); }
    );

    std::cout << (allFull ? "Filled up!\n" : "There's still some room!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    for (auto it = std::begin(twoDimArr); it != std::end(twoDimArr); ++it) {
        std::fill(std::begin(*it), std::end(*it), 1);
    }

    checkIfAllFull();
    twoDimArr.at(3).at(7) = 0;
    checkIfAllFull();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I'm not sure what a Hash_Entry is, but you can easily provide your own type and empty value via templates.